# Animating Issue

Tags: animation, import, unity

I'm really new to blender and am using it to model and animate for a game i'm currently working on.

Could someone please explain how to "properly" animate something in blender.
What I do is go into the action center click the record button and animate like that. However when I do so I get a whole bunch of junk files. I want just one clean animation with all the movements included. This is more of a nuisance than a problem.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: As it stands right now your question is too vague. Please be more specific on the steps you've taken and how exactly they are failing. It's hard to tell what you mean by "junk files". Include images that show the issues and if possible upload the file you are having  problems with.

Comment: Well, "properly" is subjective and will depend on what is being animated and who you ask. Perhaps you're wondering how to insert individual transform keyframes manually (`I`)?

Answer (score 1):

With just about anything one can do in Blender, including modeling and animating, there is often more than one way to reach the same end. This is as true of animations as it is of anything else, and means that there is not really a good answer to

> how to "properly" animate something in Blender

because how one proceeds with the animation depends upon not only what is being animated, but how what is to be animated is made, and how it will be used in the scene, to name just three considerations. You haven't provided any of that in the original question. You also don't provide any images of what you want animated, and what you want the animation to do, and how you want it to look.

My sense is that maybe you are trying something beyond your current skillset. There is nothing wrong with that, but this is not the place to enhance your skillset directly. If I were you, before trying to animate the object, I'd visit [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/), check under "online courses", and consider working through one or both of these. I think this will give you a good foundation towards what you want to do.